# Errores para instalar paquetes en R Studio

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, packages

he instalado R Studio en Ubuntu 20.04.2 y me estoy iniciando. He intentando instalar paquetes, por ejemplo:

`install.packages("plotly")`

Pero me aparecen diversos mensajes de error, de este estilo:

```
* removing ‘/home/helios/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/lazyeval’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lazyeval’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/home/helios/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
```

He leído que esto significa que tendría que instalar aparte estos paquetes en Ubuntu, pero al intentarlo me dice que o bien ya están instalados o no los encuentra. No se qué tendría que hacer, muchas gracias

Comment: checa todo el LOG de la consola, muchas veces faltan paquetes e tu distribución de ubuntu. cuando lo hagas te aparecerá algo como ****WARNING***** missing x library y ya sabrás que instalar con apt o cualquier otro manejador de paquetes

Comment: Buena idea checar todo el log para ver qué paquete falta. Una pregunta ¿cómo instalaste R? ¿A través de apt en repositorio oficial? ¿A través de otro repo?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Instalé R a partir de apt en repositorio oficial, si . Y R Studio a partir de la página oficial también. Después seguí estas instrucciones para instalar paquetes :

```add-apt-repository ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+
apt install --no-install-recommends r-cran-rstan```

El problema es que veo paquetes que faltan pero desde la terminal Ubuntu tampoco puedo instalarlos, dice "No se ha podido localizar X paquete"

Comment: Una buena opción, al menos para empezar a investigar, es  intentar instalar`rlang`, revisa todos lo errores, seguramente este faltando algún paquete  de desarrollo del sistema operativo  no de R, necesario para compilar código C/C++, por otro lado has instalado las `build-essentials` de Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que ver con detenimiento la consola de rstudio luego de intentar instalar, pues en ella te muestran el paquete que falta en tu distribución linux. Luego instalas con tu medio favorito (apt-install, apt, synaptic, etc, según sea el caso) y vuelves a reinstalar el paquete en rstudio